# Android Studio 2.4 Error:platform-tools package is not installed and SDK auto-download is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've just downloaded Android Studio 2.4 preview 2, and replaced it over my older version. I've since been getting the following error on gradle sync:

> Error:platform-tools package is not installed and SDK auto-download is
>   disabled.

Comment: I recommend you to use stable version 2.3 since you know this is a preview version and might have some problems and bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same with the Preview 4, until I download the `Android SDK Build-Tools 26-rc1` and the `Android SDK Platform-Tools 26.0.0 rc1`. Then I quit Android Studio, opened it again and no complaints anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because somehow Android SDK Platform has been uninstalled to install it again open SDK manager then click on SDK Tools. Search for Android SDK platform tools thereafter select it and click on install.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the problem like this, but i fixed by Open android AVD Manager and then click on "update platform tools" on the top right corner.